# Difficult diophantine equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Solve for integers:

$4n^4+7n^2+3n+6=m^3.$

Hi this is a problem from an Bulgarian olympiad for which I have no idea how to solve.

I figured out using wolfram alpha that $16\cdot m^3-47$ must be a square number.

I would appreciate any solutions. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are the contestants allowed to use computer programs ? Because this equation seems to be quite complicated , although I expect that someone will post an answer here soon.

Comment: Unfortunately no. The problem is from 2013 the year they forbid it. Before this it was allowed.

Comment: Maybe, modulo some number the equation turns out to be unsolvable. Otherwise, it would be hard to find a solution.

Comment: @Peter Another technique is to use bounds. E.g. $n^2+n = m^2$ can't have too many solutions.. Doubt that's applicable here though

Comment: @mathworker21 True, but here this does not seem to help very much considering the degrees of the left and the right polynomial. The left polynomial is also irreducible.

Comment: @HexMaster can you explain why $16m^3-47$ is a square

Comment: I don't expect a solution. Very large numbers if any. Heuristically input Wolfram solve integers $4n^4+7n^2+3n+13=m^3$  You will receive an answer immediately. Wolfram works with supercomputers. Although not very successful, I do not think Wolfram would be incapable of solving this equation. A solution does not seem possible. But maybe it is possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idea is going modulo $9$.

Indeed, we will prove that $4n^4 + 7n^2+3n+6$ leaves only remainders $2,5,6$ modulo $9$. None of these are cubes modulo $9$(only $0,1,8$ are), completing the proof that no such integers $n,m$ exist.

For this, we note that if $n \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ then  $4n^4 + 7n^2+3n+6 \equiv 6\pmod{9}$.

If $n \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$  then $4n^4 + 7n^2+3n+6 \equiv 2 \pmod{9}$.

Finally, if $n \equiv - 1 \pmod{3}$ then $4n^4+7n^2+3n+6 \equiv 5 \pmod{9}$.

Comment: This was an olympiad question, so was never going to be too involved : a trick is to go modulo $7$ or $9$ because these numbers have good-looking cubic residues.